# Error connecting to environment new: Error: Error querying channels: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, channel

Not able to Start Fabric Environment using IBM Blockchain platform in VS Code

All containers are up and running in docker:

[image: Screen shot of Error]